# How do I navigate to UI while a process is running?

Tags: java

I'm currently writing a simple java app. I have a menu where I can perform different functions. What I'm wanting to do is execute a process, and while that process is running, still be able to navigate around the app, choosing different options from the menu. I also want to be able to stop the process from the menu.

So suppose I had this:

```
 public class UserInterface {
      Console c = System.console();
      boolean quitFlag = false;

      public void userInput()
      {
            String choice = c.readline("> ");
            while(choice != "exit")
            {
                 switch(choice){
                      case "1":
                           startProcess();
                      break;
                      case "2":
                           endProcess();
                      break;
                 }
      }

      public void startProcess()
      {
            int i = 0;
            while(!quitFlag)
                 i = i + 1;
      }

      public void endProcess()
      {
            quitFlag = true;
      }
 }
```

How would I go about letting startProcess() continue while executing userInput()? Is there a general principle for this? How would I do it if startProcess() and endProcess() were in different classes?

Comment: The principle is Threading (or Multi-threading, or Concurrency), and this allows you to run on multiple threads on a single core of a CPU so that one process does not halt the entire execution or your program. I would suggest reading up on that. Here are some starter lessons/tutorials you could check out: [From Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) and [another one form tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm)

Comment: I will definitely check these out. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this but the simplest is via the Thread class.  The  Java docs for java.lang.Thread show examples, but the principle is that you place your separate process code inside a Thread subclass or in the run() method of a Runnable interface implementation which is passed to the Thread.
Call start() or run() on the thread to start processing. The UI thread continues independently.

Although Thread includes a stop() method, it is deprecated and the Java docs explain why.  Best practice is to create your own method that sets a flag indicating that the process should end early, and then check this flag at frequent intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
public class UserInterface {

    MyProcessor processor = null;

    ...

    public void startProcess() {
        processor = new MyProcessor();
        new Thread(processor).start();
    }

    public void endProcess() {
        if (processor != null) {
            processor.endProcess();
        }
    }

    private class MyProcessor implements Runnable {

        private boolean quitFlag = false;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i = 0;
            while (!quitFlag) {
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }

        public void endProcess() {
            quitFlag = true;
        }

    }
}
```